# Consulta SQl trazer resultado repetidos

Tags: mysql, sql

Como faço para listar apenas a coluna setor que tenha dados repetidos?
no caso, apenas mostrar o **setor 150**

```
SELECT setor,count(quantidade) as quantidade, usuario 
FROM arquivo_coletor 
GROUP BY setor,usuario 
ORDER BY setor ASC
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @HugoRutemberg. O resultado deve ser os dois registos do setor 150? Ou apenas um com o setor e a soma da quantidade? Ou outra coisa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se pretender obter apenas aqueles registos, com soma de quantidade, cuja chave `setor + usuario` tem duplicados, pode utilizar a seguinte solução:

```
SELECT      setor
        ,   SUM(quantidade) AS quantidade
FROM        arquivo_coletor
GROUP BY    setor
HAVING      COUNT(distinct setor + usuario) > 1
```

Os registos agrupados por `setor` e `usuario`:

```
SELECT      AC.setor
        ,   AC.usuario
        ,   SUM(ac.quantidade) AS quantidade
FROM        arquivo_coletor AC
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      setor
                        ,   SUM(quantidade) AS quantidade
                FROM        arquivo_coletor
                GROUP BY    setor
                HAVING      COUNT(distinct setor + usuario) > 1
            )               AC2 ON AC2.setor = AC.setor
GROUP BY    AC.setor
        ,   AC.usuario
```

Comment: ainda continua não trazendo apenas os duplicados

Comment: Algo não está bem na sua tabela, com certeza! Consegue montar um cenário no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Aqui está http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c52a39/1

Comment: O SQL Fiddle está vazio...

Comment: veja agora -  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e6a8a/1

Comment: Já percebi o seu problema! Resposta editada.

Comment: Perfeito! Agora está correto.

Comment: Aproveite e dê um UP nas respostas que considere úteis (incluindo esta) :)

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/384021-comando-contr%C3%A1rio-de-distinct/

Edit1: Segundo esta outra fonte http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find-duplicate-values/ o comando abaixo faz exatamente o que você descreveu.

```
select campo from tabela group by campo having count(*) >1
```

Edit2: Perdão, provavelmente o erro foi meu em não demonstrar na prática como ficaria este comando adaptado ao seu caso. Suponho que seja assim:

```
select setor,count(quantidade) as quantidade, usuario from arquivo coletor group by quantidade having count(quantidade) >1
```

Não manjo tanto de SQL por isso não vai uma explicação mais teórica, mas acho que ficaria assim.

Comment: Dessa forma o resultado exclui os dados em duplicidade.
Preciso que o resultado seja apenas o que tenho em duplicidade.

Comment: Vou dar outra pesquisada aqui

Comment: Não @HugoRutemberg, essa consulta traz exatamente o que precisa, ou seja, os resultados com número de registos superior a 1 (duplicados, triplicados, etc).

Comment: @João Martins, devo esta fazendo confusão 

Fiz a consulta abaixo;
`select setor,usuario from arquivo_coletor group by usuario having count(*) >1`

Resultado ficou assim;

setor | usuario
136 | 001
150 |002

Comment: Tomo como referência o segundo link, e tente adaptar o código da fonte a sua problemática.

Answer (score 0):

Da um select em todos os campos e agrupa por eles, depois da um having count>1

```
  select setor,quantidade,usuario 
     from arquivo_coletor
    group by setor,quantidade,usuario 
    having count(*) >1
```

Comment: Dessa forma ele traz dessa forma.

setor | quantidade | usuário
136   |1                  |001
136   |2                  |001
136   |4                  |001

Gostaria de enxergar assim;
setor | quantidade | usuário
150   |5                 |001
150   |5                 |002